# Files Connect to Sharepoint - nothing showing

Tags: sharepoint

I am delving into the world of the Files Connect feature in SalesForce.  I have set it up, twice now, and gotten it 'working' with a SharePoint Online account, with in O365.  I have been following the notes in the SF docs here,  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_admin_files_connect.htm&type=5  and some notes I found here, that helped a lot.  https://www.terrystidbits.com/2018/11/21/terrys-tips-integrating-salesforce-and-microsoft-office-365-sharepoint/

The Auth. Provider is up and working, same for the External Data Source to my SharePoint site.  It has validated and sync'd fine it seems.  Permission set has been set for both the 'Files Connect Cloud' as well as access to the external data source.  I have created the app inside the SharePoint site and setup the rights for it.  The user has setup the auth provider step in their profile as well.  As far as I can tell it is all working fine.

The problem is that even though there are files inside the SharePoint site they aren't showing inside SalesForce.  I have been searching the web for days now, and can't find anything like I am dealing with.  Anyone here have any ideas, or seen something like this?

Comment: So an interesting change I have found.  If I rename the folder 'Documents' inside the SharePoint site to anything else that name change shows in Salesforce.  But there is still nothing being seen inside that folder. Just doesn't make sense.  Something is working at least it seems, just not all of it.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm running into the same problem and I cannot for the life of me find a solution that resolves this.