# Files Connect to Sharepoint Online - Connected Not Showing Folders or Files - Nothing Showing

Tags: profile, permission-sets, sharepoint, files-connect

[Files Connect to Sharepoint - nothing showing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332141/files-connect-to-sharepoint-nothing-showing/415484#415484)

So the reason I'm posting this is because I found an answer to this question that seems to be plaguing multiple people across various forums and has gone unanswered for literal **YEARS** and the original post seems to be limited to users that have 50 points because I asked a question in the answer section by accident.

**Assumptions:** You have configured your MS Entra App and have set up auth. provider, external data source, and added the System Permission "Files Connect Cloud" to Permission Set on the SF side already. At the minimum, on the MS Entra App side you've provided **Delegated Permissions > Sharepoint > SitesAll.Read permissions**.

**Result:** You're authenticated, connected, but nothing is showing up. You've quadruple checked your setup, and everything looks correct according to the documentation from SF, and EVERY alternative setup guide you've read. You've trawled the depths of every forum and found the same question you have sitting unanswered for literal years, **YEARS**.

This may not solve your problem, but it solved mine.

**SOLUTION:** Add the System Permission "Files Connect Cloud" to the assigned Profile as well as the assigned Permission Set.

**NOTE:** I was unable to get files/folders in SPO to appear in the files tab of SF with the Files Connect Cloud permission added to either just the profile, or just the permission set, it had to be added to both to work.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  BTW you should be able to post your solution as an Answer to the original question, even as a new user.  StackExchange is not intended to be threaded discussion so we don't encourage posting questions or discussion into the Answers section (except as comments).  BTW you can also Answer your question and accept it, so if you can't answer the original question, you can paste your solution into an Answer here.

Comment: Hey David, when I attempt to add a comment to the original post it says I need a reputation of 50 to comment.

Comment: Right but are you seeing the Your Answer section on the page below the original question?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Add the System Permission "Files Connect Cloud" to the assigned Profile as well as the assigned Permission Set.

NOTE: I was unable to get files/folders in SPO to appear in the files tab of SF with the Files Connect Cloud permission added to either just the profile, or just the permission set, it had to be added to both to work.